# javascript: easiest way to output names from student ID

Tags: javascript, html, numbers, lookup

My JS CODE

```
<script language="Javascript">
var data = {
   7: "Jack Black",
   8: "John Smith"
};

var id = document.getElementById("id"),
  emp = document.getElementById("name");
id.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  emp.value = data[this.value] || "No name with this ID Number";
});
</script>
```

And in HTML i have

```
<input type="number" id="id" />
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="name" />
```

So what am i doing wrong, how come when i type 7, Jack Black doesn't appear inside the text box?

Many Thanks

Comment: for me, it's working. what error do you get?

Comment: Works just fine https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/429/

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem must be with the position of the script tag in the html file, you need to define the html element with id `id` before using the javascript to get the ID using `document.getElementById("id")`, this seems to be the only problem with the code.

Script content coming first and html after, causes the error

```html
<script language="Javascript">
  var data = {
    7: "Jack Black",
    8: "John Smith"
  };

  var id = document.getElementById("id"),
    emp = document.getElementById("name");
  id.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    emp.value = data[this.value] || "No name with this ID Number";
  });
</script>

<input type="number" id="id" />
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="name" />
```

If we reverse the order and define the html first, then the script, there is no error!

```html
<input type="number" id="id" />
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="name" />

<script language="Javascript">
var data = {
   7: "Jack Black",
   8: "John Smith"
};

var id = document.getElementById("id"),
  emp = document.getElementById("name");
id.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  emp.value = data[this.value] || "No name with this ID Number";
});
</script>
```

Comment: @UrbanOzzy take it as, if we define it at the head tag or at the end of the body tag, its the ideal location, if you want to insert a script tag, between html elements, then whatever elements you are referencing, must be located above the script tag, else It will not find the element!

Answer (score 1):

Your code works! But if you would like to use the arrows of the number input, use the change-event.

```js
// maybe it would be better to make an array
var data = {
   7: "Jack Black",
   8: "John Smith"
};

var id = document.getElementById("id"),
  emp = document.getElementById("name");

function changeValue() {
  emp.value = data[this.value] || "No name with this ID Number";
}

// event listener
if (id.addEventListener) { // new browsers
 id.addEventListener("keyup", changeValue, false);
 id.addEventListener("change", changeValue, false);
} else if (id.attachEvent) { // IE <9, Opera <6
 id.attachEvent("onkeyup", fchangeValue);
  id.attachEvent("onchange", fchangeValue);
} else { // old browsers
 id.onkeyup = changeValue;
  id.onchange = changeValue;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="id" />
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="name" />
```